# Edit user info from front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, frontend

I am building a website which has a registration/login system using `mongodb`.
I have successfully created an `admin` page, which can only be accessed by the admin ( `if permission > 0`).
On the `admin page` all the users are displayed showing there usernames, emails, phone numbers and `points`. What I am trying to do is to be able to `incease` the users' points using the admin account from the webpage. Here is how the users are displayed using `jade js` and how it looks on the page:

`ul
            each user, i in userlist
                li#user_list_item
                    label Username: &nbsp;
                    span #{user.username} &nbsp;
                    label Email: &nbsp;
                    span #{user.email} &nbsp;
                    label Points: &nbsp;
                    span #{user.points} &nbsp;
                    button.btn.btn-primary() +pts
                    &nbsp;
                    label Telefon: &nbsp;
                    span #{user.phoneNo} &nbsp;
                    label Permissions: &nbsp;
                    span #{user.permissions}`

[image]

Next to the points there is `button` with the name of `+pts`. When that button is pressed I want to increase the points of the user that the button is at. So say I click on the button at the first username: `admin` and therefore the points are gonna be increased by 1, so the new points are `1005`.  The labels are only to change their colors in css. How can I achieve this with one function that I can use for each button? 
Here is the `get request` which I used on the admin page.

```
router.get('/admin', isAdmin, function(req, res) {
  const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
  const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/gymsite';

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) {
          res.send({
              msg: "Failed to connect to db"
          });
      } else {
          const users = db.collection('users');

          users.find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
              if (err) {
                  res.send(err);
              } else if (result.length) {
                  res.render('admin', {
                      'userlist': result
                  });
              } else {
                  res.send({
                      msg: 'No users found'
                  });
              }
              db.close();
          });
      }
  });
```

});

`isAdmin` is a function to check whether the user `isAutheinticated` or not and if the `permissions` of that very user if it is `greater than 0`. Basically it only checks whether its an admin or not.

I hope I wrote everything clearly on what I want to achieve.

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Have you tried making a request to the server and trigger a function that increments the score?

Comment: Please add your code *as code* and not *as image*. Otherwise i will have to answer in Paint...

Comment: Now I want to see @JonasW. answer this question with a h̶a̶n̶d̶  mouse drawn image

Comment: @luca done ... I can finally watch Tatort now :)

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 2):

At first it might be useful to set up only one connection to the db, promises are helpful here, additionally we could at an utility to use the database inside of routes:

[image]

Now that we got that, the admin page can be shortened to:

[image]

Now to apply settings to users we need an API endpoint:

[image]

And you have to change the rendered html under the admin route so that you can easily work with it:

[image]

Then you only have to do a request to the API in the background, whenever update gets clicked:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Viel Spaß beim Tatort :P

Comment: It returns: 
`{"err":null,
"updated":{
       "lastErrorObject":{"n":0,"updatedExisting":false},
"value":null,"ok":1}}`

And it is not updated

Comment: The problem is probably from the last bit of code. What I did is that I made a seperate JS file with that code and imported it in the `jade` file `script(src="...")`

Comment: @ballo adam check if the `username` and `points` arrive at the server correctly

Comment: I did check and they are entered correctly. It might be from the `js` file I imported because I tried to check with `console.log` if it finished but it never `logs` it out

Comment: @ballo remove the `<form >` to disable the fallback

Comment: @JonasW. if I remove `<form>` the `action` is going to be removed as well. I tried removing the form, but on `button press` nothing happens.
With the `form` in, the page refreshed(because I changed the `res.send` to `res.redirect` but the info is not updated.

Comment: @ballo if you go with the form, change `bodyParser.json()` to `bodyParser.urlencoded()`

Comment: @JonasW. I think that everything works just fine, but for some when `update` is clicked, the code from the file that I imported doesn't start. Yet the file is imported correctly because before the code the `console.log` does show. I checked if any of the `class names` are misspelled, but they are not. I also added a `console.log` right after `forEach()` so that I can check whether it reached that point or not. Unfortunately it did not

Comment: @ballo but you added the script at the end of the page?

Comment: @JonasW. When it was at the beginning of the jade file it did not execute that code, but it did execute the `post` method. Now I moved it at the end of the file, and it does execute the code within the imported file, but in the `mongod` console it says: `/users/[object%20Object] 404` ( at the `action` in the form I did add `/users/changeUser` )

Comment: @ballo are you sure the Username is exisiting?

Comment: @JonasW. Yes. the username is existent. But if it weren't existent it wouldn't show up

Comment: @ballo and the right username arrives at the backend?

Comment: @JonasW. When I try to `console.log` the username after `users.findOneAndUpdate` it logs `undefined`

Comment: @ballo oh, it must be `$(".username", user)[0].value`, I'm sorry for that

Comment: @JonasW. so I tried to `log` the username and pts and it does get it correctly whenever I click on the buttons. It returns in the mongod shell: `/users/[object%20Object] 404`